# What is the default charset in php PDO connection string?

Tags: php, pdo

If the charset is not specified in the connection string, as per the example given in the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), which charset is used?

`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);`

The charset can be, and probably should always be, specified in the string like so:

`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', $user, $pass);`

But when it isn't specified what charset is used?

Comment: Probably the DB's charset or whats native to your system

Comment: The MySQL server will assume whatever is configured in my.ini as the default connection charset (I don't recall off the top of my head which setting specifically), what encoding PDO will assume is an interesting question.

Comment: @deceze PDO won't assume it at all, it won't set anything and the mysql default will be used. so it's utfmb4 for mysql 8 and latin1 for anything else. Uless, as you said, any other value is explicitly set in my.ini

Comment: @You In most scenarios PDO doesn't *need* to assume anything, especially with native prepared statements; but in emulated prepared statements and such PDO will have to know about the current connection encoding, is there an internal API that it will get that from? I don't know anything about the internal MySQL API to know whether such a thing exist and/or whether PDO uses it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MariaDB you can check what the charset is of your connection with this query (using your connection of course):

```
SELECT VARIABLE_NAME, SESSION_VALUE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_VARIABLES WHERE
  VARIABLE_NAME LIKE 'character_set_c%' OR
  VARIABLE_NAME LIKE 'character_set_re%' OR
  VARIABLE_NAME LIKE 'collation_c%';
```

From the https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-names/

PDO will use the default charset set for the server which is latin1 by default. This can be changed in `my.ini`

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Running the above query should have all results in utf8.